# Graphical interface to YUM in Fedora

Tags: fedora, yum

What are the options for managing `yum` software graphically in Fedora 16? and how can they be installed (if they aren't already)?

Comment: note a very quick google had a lot of people saying "I prefer synaptic" on forums, so I thought it prudent to ask this, did not find it on here either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am using YumExtender. Here are the download instructions fron the site, including the .repo file:

"The packages [are] located in the repo : http://repos.fedorapeople.org/repos/timlau/yumex/

1. download the .repo file
2. Copy it to /etc/yum.repos.d/ as root
3. install it with yum install yumex-future as root"