# Is there an equivalent of Synaptic (graphical UI) for Fedora?

Tags: fedora, yum, rpm

I use Ubuntu for many years and I like to use [Synaptic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synaptic_%28software%29) to manage packages.

I'm testing Fedora (version 20) and I'm a little bit lost. Is there an equivalent of Synaptic (a graphical tool) for Fedora?

A [previous answer from 2012](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/42562/50687) mentionned YumExtender, is there a new tool which appeared since? Is there a software manager which is present in the repositories and can be installed with `yum`?

Edit: [Wikipeda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PackageKit#Front-ends) mentions [Apper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apper) and [GNOME Software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNOME_Software). GNOME Software is installed by default, I didn't find it with Gnome Shell search because its name is *Software*, it's not translated even though I have configured the french locale in Fedora.

Edit 2: GNOME Software was also cited but [Marcelo](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/164356/50687), but it seems that it doesn't display all the available softwares. For example searching `httpd` display no result but I was able to install it with `yum install httpd`. So I'm still looking for an equivalent of Synaptic, GNOME Software seems to be too limited.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Graphical interface to YUM in Fedora 16](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/42559/graphical-interface-to-yum-in-fedora-16)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, Fedora 20 installs `gnome-software` for this purpose.  Not sure if this is exactly what you are looking for.  It is a GUI for managing and installing packages, but looks more like (or better say, wishes to look like...) MacOSX appstore.  This may or may not be of your taste, but allows you to browse installed and uninstalled packages as well as identifies the currently available updates for the installed ones.

Edit: gnome-software is Application oriented (and not package oriented), thus it may not show individual packages for webservers, libraries, etc.

**Apper**, in the other hand, does. To install Apper, just run **`yum install apper`** as root in a terminal.

Comment: Thanks, I discovered it myself in the same time you posted your answer. As you said, it looks more like a store than an utility like Synaptic but I find it more convenient than yum to search and install packages. Does it give access to all the packages? It doesn't find `apache`.

Comment: Apache2 is named httpd (see this [french wiki](http://doc.fedora-fr.org/wiki/Installation_et_configuration_d%27Apache)). But searching `httpd` in GNOME Software don't display any result. It seems that GNOME Software display only some selected softwares.

Comment: Interesting.  Unfortunately it seems you are right in regard to gnome-software being selective in what it displays.  I could not find Apache/httpd or other packages like openssh/openssl.  I confess I use yum all the time and just explored gnome-software a couple of times by curiosity.

Comment: According to this post: `http://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/2fwjz7/gnome_software_on_arch_linux/`, it seems Apper is more likely to be what you are looking for.  It states gnome-software is indeed selective and directed to the end user, while Apper is an actual package manager (never used it myself though).

Comment: Just did a quick try on Apper (`yum install apper`).  You will be able to find Apache with it.

Comment: if you are using fedora +21 (22,23 ,... )use sudo dnf install apper

Answer (score 2):

You can install [Dnfdragora](https://pkgs.org/download/dnfdragora). For me, it was somehow better than Synaptic Package Manager (but its name is a bit crappy).

To install it, simply, go to Gnome Software, search "Dnfdragora", and install it.

You can also download the RPM installation file from [here](https://fedora.pkgs.org/31/fedora-x86_64/dnfdragora-1.1.1-3.fc31.noarch.rpm.html#howto) (the Downloads section), and then install it by double-clicking it (or opening it with Software Install).